# Classifying chemical raw materials to introduce in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

I should introduce the products of a company that creates chemical, mineral and agricultural raw materials.

To explain more clearly, some examples are *Ammonium Sulfate* (as an agricultural product), *Phosphate* (as Minerals) and *Sulphuric acid* as a chemical raw material.

Reviewing http://schema.org/Product, http://schema.org/Thing, https://schema.org/docs/meddocs.html and also https://schema.org/MedicalEntity, I don't know which one (or maybe another template to use) are the best template to make use of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, these are *products* (i.e., they offer these, right?), so the [`Product` type](http://schema.org/Product) seems to be appropriate.

[`MedicalEntity`](https://schema.org/MedicalEntity) (or one of its sub-types) would only be appropriate for those products that are "related to health and the practice of medicine". If that’s the case, you could add it as *additional* type.